# Are there plans to keep the blockchain/node size small enough to maintain decentralisation?

Tags: blockchain, decentralization, node

One issue bitcoiners like to mention is node size in relation to decentralisation. Currently we are at like 10gb, I saw that the max growth is apparently 100gb a year. Are there any plans for reducing this? Or do we think technological improvements will be fast enough in the hard drive space that 100gb a year is fine? I agree with the importance of making it available to the average person to run a node.

Answer (score 6):

I assume with "*blockchain/node size*" you mean the growing size of the immutable ledger database. The current growth rate is pretty linear. In the last 100 days it grew from 7 up to 10.5 GB

[image]

So we see a **growth rate of about 1 GB per month**, which would result in a 12 GB per year.

Keep in mind the ledger DB folder now contains every UTXO action since Nov-2017, not just since Shelley-Mainnet launch in Aug-2020.

New capabilities like [Metadata](https://docs.cardano.org/projects/cardano-serialization-lib/en/latest/getting-started/metadata.html) or additional activities from [native Tokens](https://docs.cardano.org/en/latest/native-tokens/learn-about-native-tokens.html), [NFT](https://medium.com/coinmonks/nfts-in-cardano-the-earliest-projects-ab7624cc703f)s and soon Smart-Contracts may increase the growth rate a bit.

So existing Hard drives with 2-12 TeraByte capacity should provide plenty of space for the next years.