# What happen with the tAda not returned to the testnet faucet?

Tags: testnet, cardano-faucet

After using tAda on the testnet, what happen with unused remnant if for any reason it is not returned to the testnet faucet ? what are the technical implications of not return it to the faucet?

Answer (score 2):

There's no harm in holding small amounts of Ada in wallets for personal usage. If you're not going to play on the testnet anymore we ask you to return funds to the faucet. A few thousand isn't going to make much of a difference in comparison to 30 billion or so in the total system. If you're holding large sums though, please backup your wallet keys and return the funds if you retire a testnet pool, as a number of pools that have delegated stake don't make blocks anymore hurting the chain density on testnet. If we lose too much, we'll need to reset the public testnet from genesis again.

Comment: Thanks Samuel, i was just wondering what if the wallet keys get lost for whatever reason. So based on your answer i assume that little amounts do not harm, but is a good practice not poluting the testnet with any kind of lost or unused data.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the tADA will remain in test wallets and the faucet will eventually run out.

Projects that are testing and accumulating a lot of tADA (eg a DEX) should send it back once they have completed their testing.

Individual users should send back their tADA if they are not planning on using it any time soon, and request some again when they do need it in the future.

If it doesn't get sent back then eventually a new token would probably need to be created and used for testing.

Comment: Thanks MC, i was just reading this other post (https://cardano.stackexchange.com/questions/648/how-will-cardano-address-the-ledger-growth-problem) about the consequences of the ledger getting too big, and although it refers to the main net, i'm still wondering what about the testnet. Anyways, it seems there is no enough practical knowledge in this topic yet for getting some real conclusions.

Answer (score 0):

f that's why I can't request any tada to test my project. Every time I try to request some funds it says "I can't process this payment as there are not enough funds available in the wallet. I am missing: coin: 1000.000000 tokens"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://cardano.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/4021)